# Can I get all keys of a NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: key, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder

I want do something with these step:

1. Encode a kind of object A with NSKeyedArchiver M and I can get a NSData X.
2. Init another kind of object B with NSKeyedUnarchiver N from NSData X. The names of A and B are the same, so it's possible(I have done an experiment).
3. And then I want to encode B, but I do not know wether B lose some data of X, 'cause A and B may have different number of property.

So I want to get all keys and values from N. How can I do this?

I do not understand NSKeyedUnarchiver well, please help me.

Comment: Can you explain your application a bit more?

Comment: There is no official way to all the keys from NSKeyedUnarchiver. Can you tell us more about why are you trying to transfer the properties from object A to object B?